# Cannot construct instance of `class name` (although at least on Creator exists)

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have the following class, which I am using as a request payload :

```
public class SampleRequest {

    private String fromDate;
    private String toDate;

    // Getters and setters removed for brevity.
}
```

I am trying to use it with this resource below (just trying to print it to screen to see things happen) :

```
@PostMapping("/getBySignatureOne")
public ResponseEntity<?> getRequestInfo(@Valid @RequestBody SampleRequest signatureOneRequest) {

    System.out.println(signatureOneRequest.getToDate);
    System.out.println(signatureOneRequest.getFromDate);
}
```

This is the JSON request I send up :

```
{
    "fromDate":"2019-03-09",
    "toDate":"2019-03-10"
}
```

This is the error I get :

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.app.payload.SampleRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('fromDate'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.app.payload.SampleRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('fromDate')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]]
```

I'd love to know what's wrong here, I suspect its an issue with constructors, or that I am missing some annotation somewhere, but I am honestly unsure of where I have gone wrong.

Comment: What's your JSON request? Do you have constructors in SampleRequest ? If yes, you need to have default constructor as well.

Comment: @cosmos - Bah, I knew I was going to forget to provide something!! I just edited the question with the json I send up :)

Comment: Adding the default contstructor did it for me!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need a constructor with all parameters:

```
public SampleRequest(String fromDate, String toDate) {

    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;

}
```

Or using `@AllArgsConstructor` or `@Data` from lombok.

Comment: Ah, so that fixed my main error - but for somme reason I seem to be seeing null values for the fields when I am printing them to screen... Any idea what might be causing that? I'm also happen to open a new question for that if we don't want to derail this one!

Comment: @slippy see my post

Answer (score 8):

In my case i was missing the No Args contructor

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
```

for those who are not using **Lombok** do add no args constructor in the mapping pojo

```
public ClassA() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

also dont forget to add the Bean of **Restemplate** in main file if you are using the same

Answer (score 5):

Hi you need to write custom deserializer as it not able to parse String (fromDate and toDate) to Date

> {
>       "fromDate":"2019-03-09",
>       "toDate":"2019-03-10"
>   }

this link has a tutorial to get started with custom deserializer https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Deserializer could be written like this.

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

public CustomDateDeserializer() {
    this(null);
}

public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
}

@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    String date = jsonparser.getText();
    try {
        return formatter.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}}
```

You can register the deserializer at Class itself like this.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ItemDeserializer.class)
public class Item {  ...}
```

Or either you can register custom deserializer manually like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Item.class, new ItemDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was incorrect method usage: I used `ObjectMapper::convertValue`, but should've used `ObjectMapper::readValue` to convert my JSON from Rabbit to POJO.

As a result of the mistake this error appeared:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `com.hrsinternational.tng4.common.attributes.dto.order.BookingDatesResource` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"...."}') at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]