# How can we convert String to List<ClassName> in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectmapper

```
public class ClassName implements Serializable {

    String body;

    String id;

   List<Object> attachements;
}
```

I need to convert a string [{"body":"Body Message","id":"12345","attachments":[]}] to List object.

I tried using ObjectMapper but it failed as 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `ClassName` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"body":"Body Message","id":"12345","source":2,"attachments":[],}')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

Is there any simple to way to map these object to the original class.

Comment: Show us the code you're using for deserialization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot construct instance of \`class name\` (although at least on Creator exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032293/cannot-construct-instance-of-class-name-although-at-least-on-creator-exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:
`new ObjectMapper().readValue("[{\"body\":\"Body Message\",\"id\":\"12345\",\"attachments\":[]}]", List.class);`

See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array

Complete example:

```java
package com.company;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<ClassName> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue("[{\"body\":\"Body Message\",\"id\":\"12345\",\"attachments\":[]}]", List.class);
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
    }

    public static class ClassName implements Serializable {
        String body;

        String id;

        List<Object> attachements;
    }
}
```